# How can I use a listener to change the background color of JFrame (Java)?

Tags: java, swing, listener, background-color

So I have to make a GUI that pulls up a list of color names as radio buttons, When you click on a button, it changes the background to that color. Problem is, when I click on buttons, it doesn't change the color. This is my listener:

```
ActionListener buttons = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setBackground(Color.decode("#" + getColor()));
        repaint();
    }
};
```

getColor() returns a 6-digit hexidecimal code for the color selected. My actual code is rather long and tedious (haven't gotten the hang of creating GUI components through loops and it has 20 buttons) but I can post it upon request. The problem, I am fairly certain, lies within the block of code that I posted.

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of Jframe container?

Comment: I am trying to change the background color of the window that the radio buttons are displayed in.

Comment: *"My actual code is rather long"*  Your (long) code is irrelevant, but for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It should not take more than 20-50 lines of code to include that method in an SSCCE.

Comment: My SSCCE (first one, sry if it sucks) is posted as a reply

Comment: *"as a reply"*  To where or whom?  I see no SSCCE.

Comment: it wouldn't let me do it this morning. It's up now.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use:

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#" + getColor()));
```

Comment: I tried getContentPane(), no such luck.

Comment: Do you have your `ActionListener` registered with your button? Post a shortened [sccee](http://sscce.org/) verison of your code

Comment: I tested this suggestion and found it to work.  Note that `decode()` requires a 'full-length' string like `a0b0c0` rather than the common abbreviation of `abc` to work correctly.

Comment: @user2302019 Use `p1.setBackground(...)` since `p1` is your main panel